# Redis Configuration settings are changing dynamically after couple of hours

Tags: redis, ubuntu-18.04

I installed Redis Server on the cloud machine (Ubuntu 18.0) where it contains SSD.
In the configuration file, I changed the dir to /temp and the dbfilename to dump.rdb
I restarted the server and checked the runtime settings with CONFIG GET.
It is showing the values what I set in the redis.conf file.

After 6 Hours, I checked it again. The strange thing is, these values got changed dir=/var/spool/cron"
and dbfilename=root.

I am sure, nobody attacked my server and it is under our own VPN and not publicly accessible.

Now, I did one more test, I installed a Docker Container (Ubuntu 18.0) in that cloud instance (Same instance) and did the test in the container. There is no change in the configuration at runtime after couple of hours.

Also, suspect if the cloud machine is built with magnetic HDD redis seems working fine. If I built with SSD then redis not working after couple of hours.

Can anybody help in this regard.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation on the my Redis server.

If your Redis server is accessible from the public network, It might be an attack.

In my case, I changed the default port of Redis servers and add password protection.

After that, the same situation does not happen.

Check the below issue in Redis GitHub, You can get more information about your case.

https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/3594